# How to print a tooltip message using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, tooltip

`                    [image]
How to write code to print a tooltip message in python?

I am using the following code to move my pointer to the element on the web page:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("locator")
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
time.sleep(3)
```

Also, our developer is using the same class for all the tool tip messages on that page so I don't know how to print that particular tooltip message.

HTML code:

```
<div class="d3-tip n" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; pointer-events: none; top: 1108px; left: 116px;"><div><strong>Table Name:</strong> <span style="color:#1F77B4">lineitem</span></div><div><strong>Number of Queries:</strong> <span style="color:#1F77B4">13</span></div></div>
```

I want to print the "lineitem" and "13" from the above div tag

But as I mentioned this is another div tag with the same class that has a different tool tip message:

```
<div class="d3-tip n" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; pointer-events: none; top: 469px; left: -180.23684692382813px;">select s_suppkey, s_name, s_address, s_phone, total_revenue from supplier s join revenue r on s.s_suppkey = r.supplier_no join (select max(total_revenue) as m from revenue) mr on r.total_revenue = mr.m order by s_suppkey </div>
```

Comment: Please show the example html code containing several tooltips, note which one you need. Thanks.

Comment: div class="d3-tip n" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; pointer-events: none; top: 1108px; left: 116px;"><div><strong>Table Name:</strong> <span style="color:#1F77B4">lineitem</span></div><div><strong>Number of Queries:</strong> <span style="color:#1F77B4">13</span></div></div -- I want to print the "lineitem" and "13" from the above div tag

Comment: Please edit the question and include the html into it.

Comment: But as I mentioned this is another div tag with the same class that has a different tool tip message div class="d3-tip n" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; pointer-events: none; top: 469px; left: -180.23684692382813px;">select
 s_suppkey,
 s_name,
 s_address,
 s_phone,
 total_revenue
from supplier s join revenue r on s.s_suppkey = r.supplier_no 
                join (select max(total_revenue) as m from revenue) mr on r.total_revenue = mr.m
order by
 s_suppkey
</div

Comment: Ok, thanks. You can use the fact that those tooltips are in different parts of a web page and find the right one based on it's parent and page location, using `xpath` expression. It's impossible to help you, since I don't know where these `div` tags are on a web page. Could you share a link?

Comment: Cannot log in, could you just show more html including several parents of the tooltips?

Comment: Please find attached is an image of some of the HTML code

Comment: Hi, now I am trying to print the other tool tip message that has the same Class as above. I wrote the following code but it is not working. I have attached the HTML for that.                   position = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='d3-tip n']")
                tooltipmessage = position.get_attribute('style')
                 if tooltipmessage == "position: absolute; opacity: 0; pointer-events: none; top: 317.5px; left: 141.48248291015625px;":
                          print tooltipmessage.text

Comment: I just discovered that the position is also changing for this tooltip message so cannot use that to find the tool tip message. Is there any other way we can identify this uniquely? Please help.. Thanks

Comment: Difficult to say. Could you please formulate a separate question out of it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501764/unable-to-read-text-from-a-div-tag-in-python/23501942?noredirect=1#23501942

Comment: for position in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='d3-tip n']"):
                        style = position.get_attribute('style')
                        opacity = style[:32]
                        if opacity == "position: absolute; opacity: 1;":
                           tooltipmessage = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@style,"%s")]' % opacity)
                           time.sleep(3)
                           print tooltipmessage.text}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the info you've provided, you can get the desired `div` by the text inside.

For example, you can check for `Table Name:` text using the xpath:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[./div/strong, 'Table Name:']")
```

Comment: Hi, The question is not related to the above issue but just wanted to ask you if you could help me on "how we can create a Test Suite" in python. I have a couple of test cases and I want to add them to a Test Suite so I can execute both of them at once from the command prompt without calling them individually. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: @user3587233 instead of making a test suite, consider using nose or py.test test runner. It would discover your test cases automagically.

Comment: Sorry, it might be a very silly question but what if I want to include only some tests in a single run and not all the test cases from that directory? Will nose help me with that too?

Comment: Hi, Can I ask your help with an xpath expression for a different issue in this question?

Comment: @user3587233 probably creating a separate question would be a good idea. Throw a link to it here in comments. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434667/how-to-formulate-the-xpath-expression-from-the-following-html

Comment: Hi Alec.. Can you please help me with the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397326/how-to-open-multiple-instances-of-firefox-using-python/24397444?noredirect=1#comment37769124_24397444

Comment: `def test_load(self):
        self.driver = []
        for i in range(2):
           self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
           url = "http://node-staging.xplain.io/"
           self.driver.get(url)
           browsers = self.driver

           browsers.find_element_by_css_selector("#initial-signup-email").send_keys("lalithac78@yahoo.com")
           browsers.find_element_by_id("try-it-free-btn").click()

           browsers.quit()`

Comment: I would like to access each browser separately to enter a different username and different actions on each browser. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @user3587233 looks like you've received a good answer. Any problems with it?