# How to formulate the Xpath expression from the following HTML

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

[image]

Hi,

I would like to write an xpath expression to **ONLY** print the text for all the "class - insights type1". I don't need to print the ones that has "hide" .

Following CSS selector gives me all the  tags for the Insights popup

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#body > div.side-module.expanded > div.content")
```

Can someone help with this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do this:

```
//div[@class="content"]/div[@class="insights type1"]
```

In python call [`find_elements_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath) and get the text of each div found:

```
for div in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="content"]/div[@class="insights type1"]'):
    print div.text
```

Note that if you need only one single div, use just [`find_element_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element_by_xpath):

```
div = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="content"]/div[@class="insights type1"]')
print div.text
```

Also, if these `div`s can be outside of `content` `div` too - use `//div[@class="insights type1"]`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have one more [@class="insights type 2"] on the same level in the same div and I want to print both "type 1" and "type 2" classes. Will any of the following work? ("//div[@class='content'][/div[@class='insights type1']][/div[@class='insights type2']]") OR ("[//div[@class='content']/div[@class='insights type1']] and [//div[@class='content']/div[@class='insights type2']]")

Comment: @user3587233 try this one: `//div[@class="content"]/div[@class="insights type1" or @class="insights type2"]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485484/how-to-formulate-an-xpath-expression-to-get-an-attribute-from-a-child-node-in-py

Comment: hey, can you please help me with the above question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome's Dev Tools for this.

Fire up the dev tools using F12, and just right-click the element whose xpath you want.

Then use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) to process the xml tree.

[image]