# How to formulate an Xpath expression to get an attribute from a child node?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

[image]

Want to formulate an Xpath expression that can get attribute "Style" from the rect tag. 
I wrote the following code but doesn't work.

Also, after getting the Style attribute I only want the rgb(); text. How can I do this?

Thanks

```
   for element in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#workload-analysis-chart > div > svg > g"):
            style = element.get_attribute('style')
            print style
```

Comment: What is the reference xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the element by `xpath` using [`find_element_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) and then get the `style` attribute using [`get_attribute()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_attribute#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method:

```
rect = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="workload-analysis-chart"]/div/svg/g/g[@data-selected="true"]/rect')
print rect.get_attribute('style')
```

Answer (score 3):

The expression is not xpath, but a css selector.

Changing the expression as following will print the style attributes:

```
for rect in root.cssselect('#workload-analysis-chart > div > svg > g > g > rect'):
    style = rect.get('style')
    print style
```

Answer (score 0):

try using lxml it have nice xpath feature

```
root = lxml.html.fromstring(pagesource)
#get rect with data-eid="10"
rect = root.xpath('//rect[@data-eid="10"]')
r = rect[0] #^returned list of rects
style = r.get("default-fill")
```