# Unable to read text from a div tag in python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

`for position in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='d3-tip n']"):
                        style = position.get_attribute('style')
                        opacity = style[:32]
                        if opacity == "position: absolute; opacity: 1;":
                           tooltipmessage = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@style,"%s")]' % opacity)
                           time.sleep(3)
                           print tooltipmessage.text`I have 2 div tags with the same class ("d3-tip n"). When I hover the mouse the Opacity changes to "1" in the style attribute and I want to print the text from that div tag.

I wrote the following code and for some reason it does not print anything.

NOTE - I also tried position.text and that doesn't work either.

Attached is the HTML code that shows the 2 div items with the same class and the one with the SQL query is the text I want to print.
[image]

```
for position in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="d3-tip n"]'):
                    style = position.get_attribute('style')
                    opacity = style[:32]
                    if opacity == "position: absolute; opacity: 1;":
                       print position
```

Comment: in the html code `opacity: 0`. But in py your checking for  `opacity: 1`

Comment: When I hover my mouse the opacity changes to 1.

Comment: So, you have 2 `div` tags, you need only one. Is the order of the tooltips the same all of the time? In other words, you can get the first `div` out of 2..

Comment: Yes, the order is the same.. I amended my code that I am using in the actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just get the first `div` out of 2 found found by the class name:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="d3-tip n"]')[0]
print element.text
```

Another option is to check that there are no children in the `div` tag:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="d3-tip n"][count(*)=0]')
print element.text
```

Another option is to check that there is `select` text inside the `div` text:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="d3-tip n"][contains(text(), "select")]')
print element.text
```

Comment: Gives me this error TypeError: 'WebElement' object does not support indexing

Comment: @user3587233 if you are trying first option, watch the `s` in the `find_elements_by_xpath` method.

Comment: Hi, can you please help me with the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771089/how-to-formulate-an-xpath-expression-in-python-locate-all-the-elements-in-a-pie