# How to formulate an Xpath expression in python locate all the elements in a pie chart (onion ring)?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

[image]`<div class="join-strength-chart">
  <svg width="350" height="300">
  <g transform="translate(175,150)">
    <path d="M0,-140A140,140 0 0,1 0,-140L0,-90A90,90 0 0,0 0,-90Z" style="fill: rgb(158, 202, 225);"></path>
    <path d="M0,-140A140,140 0 0,1 0,-140L0,-90A90,90 0 0,0 0,-90Z" style="fill: rgb(107, 174, 214);"></path>
    <path d="M0,-140A140,140 0 0,1 134.55816974212192,-38.65357623364557L86.50168054850695,-24.848727578772156A90,90 0 0,0 0,-90Z" style="fill: rgb(66, 146, 198);"></path>
    <path d="M134.55816974212192,-38.65357623364557A140,140 0 0,1 134.55816974212192,-38.65357623364557L86.50168054850695,-24.848727578772156A90,90 0 0,0 86.50168054850695,-24.848727578772156Z" style="fill: rgb(33, 113, 181);"></path>
    <path d="M134.55816974212192,-38.65357623364557A140,140 0 0,1 -6.02311262063425,139.87037611431205L-3.872000970407732,89.91667035920061A90,90 0 0,0 86.50168054850695,-24.848727578772156Z" style="fill: rgb(8, 81, 156);"></path>
    <path d="M-6.02311262063425,139.87037611431205A140,140 0 0,1 -29.89292816157139,136.77138898880526L-19.21688238958161,87.92446434994623A90,90 0 0,0 -3.872000970407732,89.91667035920061Z" style="fill: rgb(116, 196, 118);"></path>
    <path d="M-29.89292816157139,136.77138898880526A140,140 0 0,1 -130.73721203520947,-50.07775343663755L-84.04535059406322,-32.19284149498128A90,90 0 0,0 -19.21688238958161,87.92446434994623Z" style="fill: rgb(65, 171, 93);"></path>
    <path d="M-130.73721203520947,-50.07775343663755A140,140 0 0,1 -130.73721203520947,-50.07775343663755L-84.04535059406322,-32.19284149498128A90,90 0 0,0 -84.04535059406322,-32.19284149498128Z" style="fill: rgb(35, 139, 69);"></path>
    <path d="M-130.73721203520947,-50.07775343663755A140,140 0 0,1 -35.7494613162662,-135.35869390473883L-22.981796560456843,-87.01630322447495A90,90 0 0,0 -84.04535059406322,-32.19284149498128Z" style="fill: rgb(0, 109, 44);"></path>
    <path d="M-35.7494613162662,-135.35869390473883A140,140 0 0,1 -2.5717582746235667e-14,-140L-1.6532731765437215e-14,-90A90,90 0 0,0 -22.981796560456843,-87.01630322447495Z" style="fill: rgb(158, 202, 225);"></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>`

Please find attached is the pie chart and the HTML.

I am trying to hover over all the segments in the attached pie chart to print the tooltip message that the app shows.

I wrote the following code and it only hovers the mouse on 1 segment for some reason.

```
for elements in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='join-strength-chart']"):
            elements = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('path')
            webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elements).perform()
            time.sleep(2)
            tooltipmessage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='d3-tip joined-tables-chart n']")
            print tooltipmessage.text
```

I did try using driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('path') and that doesn't work either.

Can someone please help?
Thank you[image]

> 

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are searching for `path` using `driver.find_element_by_tag_name()`. In other words you are finding the first `path` element on a page on every iteration of the loop.

You need to find it inside the every `div` in the loop:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='join-strength-chart']"):
    path = element.find_element_by_tag_name('path')
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(path).perform()
    ...
```

Comment: I tried the above and it still only points to 1 segment in the Joined Tables pie chart instead iterating through all the segments.

Comment: @user3587233 ok, can you share the link to the website so I can test it? If not, just provide a relevant html (in a text form) including the `tooltipmessage` you are printing later in the loop. Thanks.

Comment: I added the HTML for the Joined tables pie chart and attached the HMTL code for the tooltip message that I am printing.

Comment: Hi Alecxe, did you get a chance to look at the above question. Could you please help me with this? Thank you

Comment: No but now I am able to get all the path elements and was able to hover all the segments but now my problem is that it prints the same tooltip message multiple times.  `for elements in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='join-strength-chart']"):
                for path in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('path'):
                     webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(path).perform()
                       tooltipmessage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='d3-tip joined-tables-chart n']":
                       print tooltipmessage.text`

Answer (score 0):

The XPath expression

```
//div[@class='join-strength-chart']
```

will return a node-set of `<div>` elements that have a `class` attribute with the value `join-strength-chart`. You can loop the node-set if you have many of those (is that the case?)

This expression:

```
//div[@class='join-strength-chart']//path
```

will return a node-set of all the `<path>` elements that are inside those `<div>`s. If you only have one `<div>` of that class in the file, it would make sense to use this expression, since it already gives you all the `<path>` elements. If you have many `join-strength-charts` maybe not, since this will return *all* paths from all of them.